# child element overlapped by box-shadow

Tags: html, z-index, overlap, css

Hy guys,

i've got a problem: The box-shadow from .elem3 should not overlap .elem2.
I tried to fix this with the z-index. First I thought it was a bug in IE,
but in all Browsers it's the same result.

Does anybody know an answer?

..sry for my bad English I'm german :)

HTML:
`

```
    <div class="elem1">
        <div class="elem2">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="elem3">

    </div>`
```

CSS:

`

```
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .elem1 {
            position: absolute;
            height: 50px;
            width: 400px; 
            background: linear-gradient(top, #70ACD7, #005DA8);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #70ACD7, #005DA8);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #70ACD7, #005DA8);
            z-index: 1;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .elem2 {
            position: absolute;
            height: 50px;
            width: 100px;
            margin-left: 100px;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #CCC, #AAA);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CCC, #AAA);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #CCC, #AAA);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(170,170,170) 43%, rgb(204,204,204) 72%);
            z-index: 3;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px black;
        }

        .elem3 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 70px;
            left: 100px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 100px;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #AAA, #CCC);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #AAA, #CCC);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #AAA, #CCC);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(170,170,170) 43%, rgb(204,204,204) 72%);
            z-index: 2;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px black;
        }
```

`

Comment: Here's a fiddle for anyone else looking at this! http://jsfiddle.net/RVhas/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not going to be possible as `elem2` is a child of `elem1` and a child can't have a higher z-index than it's parent, you will have to remove `elem2` from `elem1`, like this:

```
<div class="elem1"></div>
<div class="elem2"></div>
<div class="elem3"></div>
```

You can position it back where it was by adding a `margin-top: 20px` to `elem2`. Then give `elem1` a z-index of 1, `elem2` a z-index of 3 and `elem3` a z-index of 2.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hm thx but the box-shadow of `.elem3` should be overlap `.elem1` and `.elem3` should be overlapped by `.elem2`. It should look like `.elem2` and `.elem3` are one div with a box-shadow.